# Desktop seems to be unconnected to network

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, connection

I'm very bad at networking but I'd like some help if possible please. I'm trying to connect my VR Headset (Quest 2) to my desktop wirelessly but my desktop seems to not be in the network.

Details on what I am able to do so far:

- I am able to create a DLNA server on my phone and watch the videos there on my headset but when I try to do one with PLEX on the desktop my headset can't find it.
- I can't connect to the desktop Oculus app wirelessly with the headset using Air Link but I can connect with a wired cable.
- I tried pinging my phone from the desktop but it says host is unreachable.
  [The network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnYHY.png)
  [My pings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy7Q6.png)

I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thank you so much!

Comment: Go to Windows 10 Settings, Devices, and then look in there for your headset and how you might connect it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't seem to find my headset. I can see this image https://bashify.io/images/8KWig1 . I tried to add a new device but I seem to get stuck on this page. I also seem to be seeing the Oculus Virtual Audio Device and I'm not sure what it is but all I can do is to remove the device.

Comment: Find out from the manufacturer if the headset is windows 10 compliant and if so how to see it and install it

Comment: I'm supposed to use the Oculus App which I have https://bashify.io/images/Ird9H4 . I'm supposed to get something like this https://bashify.io/images/wGp2l9 but I get stuck at "Searching for PCs" since I think my desktop can't be found through the network.

Comment: Try this Life Wire link:    https://www.lifewire.com/connect-meta-oculus-quest-2-to-pc-wirelessly-6363079

Comment: I get stuck after step 9 even with the note. I think my desktop is not connected to the network somehow. My desktop is currently wired while my headset is connected to the 5gz wifi network.

Comment: Have you got a 5 GHz wireless card?  And if so is it properly using 5 GHz?

Comment: I'm very sorry I'm not so knowledgeable about this. Isn't this for connecting the desktop to the network through wifi? I have my desktop connected via lan cable.

Comment: I think you need a 5 GHz wireless connection on your computer for this work. I have not actually used one of these before, but when I connect according to directions it normally works for me.

Comment: Oculus recommends that the desktop be connected wired though since latency issues will pop up if the PC is connected via wifi as well.

Comment: I think you now need to contact the manufacturer. Articles I have looked at including the one I posted all have the same basic approach.

Comment: I think it's a PC network issue since I have no problem connecting to my phone. I also can't detect DLNA servers from the PC (Plex) but have no problem connecting to the DLNA on the phone. I also can't ping my phone (or any other devices) from my desktop. Thanks for the help though! I appreciate it!

Comment: See if this Sony article sheds light. ......   https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/support/articles/00106319